How to save and load TensorFlow Decision forest model for incremental learning?
I am developing TensorFlow decision forest regression model for incremental learning, So I have developed the model and have saved the model. When I retrain with new data the error is coming like "ValueError: The model's task attribute (CLASSIFICATION) does not match the task attribute passed to pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset (REGRESSION)."
I have tried saving it in different format, but still getting the error.
